# Bind Button of MDDropDownMenu KivyMD

Tags: python, binding, bind, kivy-language, kivymd

I have an MDTextField on a Screen in KivyMD. The desired procedure is to open an MDDropDownMenu on the on_focus event of the TextField. Furthermore, once you select an element of the DropDownMenu, such menu will be dismissed and the text of the selection will be added to the MDTextField.

I coded successfully the first part of the procedure. Nevertheless, it is the binding of the button which I can't seem to get right. I get no error message, but it seems like the binding function is never called.

Here is my Kivy code:

```
<TravelManagerWindow>:
    MDTextField:
        id: dest_dropdown_item
        pos_hint: {"x":0, 'center_y': 0.5}
        write_tab: False
        size_hint: 1, None
        icon_right: 'arrow-down-drop-circle-outline'
        text:'Seleccionar'
        on_focus: if self.focus: root.display_dropdown()
```

Here is my Python code:

```
class TravelManagerWindow(Screen):
    def display_dropdown(self):
        # Create the drop down menu
        menu_items = [{"text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.dest_dropdown_item,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu.open()
        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.set_item)

    def set_item(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        def set_item(interval):
            self.ids.dest_dropdown_item.text = instance_menu_item.text
            instance_menu.dismiss()
        Clock.schedule_once(set_item, 0.5)
```

I believe the set_item function is not even called, nevertheless, menu.open() does trigger correctly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install kivymd from master branch.

Do pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1):

Same issue,

I've kivymd 0.104.1

I solved by installing 0.104.2dev

pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

Answer (score -1):

By the time I'm writing this, installing kivy fromk master branch not only didnt fix the problem but it made it even worse.

EDIT: Found a fix for non master branch install

```
self.menu_items=[{"text": f"{item}"} for item in self.itens]

self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
                                caller=self.nome,
                                items=self.menu_items,
                                position="bottom",
                                width_mult=4,
                                #Here you'll put that bind func
                                callback = self.function 
                                )     

def function(self,instance):
    #Prints the text of the menu item instance
    print(instance.text)
```